# manage non local sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have started working with databases lately, I was able to create a local database and manage it in my Android app. Now I want to move to higher level with it but I don't know how to do it.

The users in my app need to be able to modify the database, for example insert new data in it. When a user insert new data in the database I want other users to see this change in their copy of the database.

I understand that I will need to store that database on a server or something and synchronize it with the users.

Can anyone tell me the steps to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perfom this task in steps.

First, make the local database, and use a system to know when/what changed.
I usually work with triggers myself, but any "mark" is enough to synchronize.

Then, you must make a replica of that database somewhere else. Realise that maintaining the databases is a process, any change in the structure of one database must be performed in all other as well.

Finally, you must implement a method to transfer the data.

So, for an example:

`db_local` the database in the device.
`db_outside` the database in the internet.

`db_local.trigger -> onInsert`

On the applications, check for internet, then connect to your server, then upload the same command to `db_outside` and run it...

In this step, you must handle connection issues, and if the SQL command was succesfully executed, you have replicated the database content.

Once you have the replicated database, inform a system (like google cloud messaging), that the database was changed, and have the other users pull the info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but I still have some questions as I haven't done it before. Where on the internet should I place the DB?  Is there some free service for such thing or should I buy something?

Comment: @Alaa it depends heavily on your knowledge of how the internet systems work. You could use any service for this, even host on your local machine (if you ISP allows it). In Brazil, where I am, a hosting service costs around 50 dollars per year, so, hosting is the best path...in the hosting service, usually a database tool is made available (MySQL is the most common one)

Comment: So if I use Mysql I don't have to host the database on my local machine?

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. You are going to have to choose how your system will be like. You could have 1 database, with all the information, and all users connect there, and all work on a single base, or have several bases, and keep a subsystem to synchronize all databases. Its pretty much the same effort on both cases, but depends on your application. In all cases, you will need at least 1 database, so a Client/Server is the most common one.

Comment: if I want to have one database with all the info and the users connect to it to get the information, where should I put the database?? I'm sorry but I'm not able to understand it as I never tried it before. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I am glad to help. But, you must tell me about the system: What is it like, is it LAN (Local Area Network) only? Is it Internet based? Do your app/program requires Internet to work (as in it does not work offline), etc... there are many details that will alter your system to your need. If what you need is something like a mass message system, where several users should see the same information (like a web-store), then what you need is a system with a database, and a link access to those informations (Check WAMP for beginners) Then you could have a web-server host it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87281/discussion-between-bonatti-and-alaa).